# Template type constructor parameters

Tags: c++, templates

Given a template class:

```
template<class T>
class Foo
{
public:
    void FunctionThatCreatesT()
    {
        _object = new T;
    }
private:
    shared_ptr<T> _object;
}
```

Is it possible to somehow pass a set of constructor parameters for T to Foo (perhaps when Foo is constructed) such that Foo can use them when it creates T? A C++11 only solution is fine (so, variadics are on the table for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly that, variadic templates and perfect forwarding via `std::forward`.

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

template<class T>
class Foo
{
public:
    template<class... Args>
    void FunctionThatCreatesT(Args&&... args)
    {
        _object = new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> _object;
}
```

For a listing of how this works, see [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward/3582313#3582313).

You can emulate a limited version of this in C++03 with many overloaded functions, but.. it's a PITA.

Also, this is only from memory, so no testing done. Might contain an off-by-one error.